# Text formatting CVS-friendly

Tags: cursor-motions, formatting, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

I have seen this very interesting article: http://dustycloud.org/blog/vcs-friendly-patchable-document-line-wrapping/ --- basically it is a suggestion for hard-breaking lines of text (for example, in markdown or LaTeX sources) to achieve both easy readability and easy "diff"-ability.

Basically, when I write in LaTeX normally I follow the classical way of "one line per phrase" (hard new line at full stop), and the mandatory blank line for paragraph. This is unfortunately almost unreadable in a `diff` of a very long phrase, especially if the change is near the end.

The suggested format is to have a line format (a la `gqip`) for every phrase, but keeping the phrases on their own. For example:

```
This is a short phrase. This, instead, is a very long, probably too long for English, phrase, but in other languages very long phrases are quite common, really --- and so on and so on.
```

should be formatted as (this has `setl tw=60` to be more dramatic)

```
This is a short phrase. 
This, instead, is a very long, probably too long for
English, phrase, but in other languages very long phrases
are quite common, really --- and so on and so on.
```

I can go from the first form to the final one by hand:

1. format the paragraph with `gqip`;
2. go to the first full stop (or question mark, or a symbol meaning the end of the sentence);
3. if it is the end of the paragraph, stop;
4. otherwise, insert a linebreak;
5. then go to the next line, format again the *rest* of the paragraph as in point 1 above (still searching how to do this effectively --- clearly `gqip` do not work here unless I temporarily add a blank line above);
6. repeat until the end of the paragraph.

Is there a way to apply such a type of formatting *automatically* to a paragraph?

Comment: Hmm... http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/how-to-set-up-vim-to-work-with-one-sentence-per-line?rq=1 is very similar...

Comment: I don't quite understand what the question is here...

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg, you are right. Explained better now, I hope.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand the question better now. I don't have the answer, but I have some hints. Check out `:h formatexpr` - you can define a custom function for the `gq` command. Also check out `:h formatoptions`, which can be used to apply the formatter automatically for various scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than changing the way text is actually stored by writing a custom `'formatexpr'`, I'd be tempted to just to use Vim's existing features to solve the stated goals of easy readability and easy "diff"-ability.

Long lines are easily readable in Vim with the following set:

```
:set wrap
:set linebreak
```

And changes towards the end of a line are also perfectly readable when using Vim for diffing (`:help diff`), so long as you ensure 'wrap' is switched on while you view the diff. (It's off by default).

There's at least one plugin ([cvsmenu](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1245)) that allows you to use Vim for viewing CVS diffs.

If you need to diff *outside* of Vim, there are tools that can help with this too: e.g. [wdiff](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/), or [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)'s  `--word-diff` option.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but I really like my text physically formatted --- so that I can have a glance using `less`, or `cat` it, or whatever...

Comment: @Rmano Hopefully someone will be along soon to explain how you can get a more direct solution working with `'formatexpr'` (Or you figure it out for yourself.)