# Make autoformating insert a line break instead of two spaces after full stop

Tags: formatting, filetype-tex, git

I noticed that vi's auto format adds two spaces after a full stop. I wonder how this can be changed, i.e., insert just one space after a full stop, or even a line break.

The application is in using a line based version control system such as `git` for editing text documents (`LaTeX` in particular). With the convetion of breaking lines at full stops, changes to an autoformatted paragraph would be confined to modified sentences.

Comment: Which commands are you using? `gq`?

Comment: Yes. gq{movement}

Comment: One of my previous questions ["How to set up Vim to work with one sentence per line?"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/how-to-set-up-vim-to-work-with-one-sentence-per-line) shares some overlap with the "line based version control and LaTeX" part of your question. There might be some answers for you there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Vim joins a line that ends with a period to another line, it inserts two spaces between them. This is because `joinspaces` is on by default. To make `gq` only insert one space between lines, use:

```
:set nojs
```

Vim is also set to collapse lines shorter than textwidth with `gq`. To make `gq` not join lines together, you can use the format option `w`:

```
:set fo+=w
```

This option makes vim only collapses lines that end with a space.

I hope this helps! For more information see [`:help js`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27js%27) and [`:help fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table).