# How to format quotes, so that Vim breaks long lines into multiple quotes on multiple lines?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, formatting

For example, suppose I have this line of JavaScript:

```
console.log(
   "This is a really long line that I want to format, and it is inside of a quote"
)
```

I'd like to select the quote line in VISUAL-LINE mode, the pres `gq` to format it, but it doesn't work. The result is something like this:

```
console.log(
  "This is a really long line that I want to
  format, and it is inside of a quote"
)
```

but I was hoping that it would be something like this:

```
console.log(
  "This is a really long line that I want to "+
  "format, and it is inside of a quote"
)
```

so that the result is still a proper string.

Is it possible to do this with Vim?

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth: [`:h gq`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#gq) explains that you have 3 ways to format your code with `gq`

> ```
> 1. If 'formatexpr' is not empty the expression is
>    evaluated. This can differ for each buffer.
> 2. If 'formatprg' is not empty an external program
>    is used.
> 3. Otherwise formatting is done internally.
> ```

Let's begin with the third option: the internal formatting is controlled by `'formatoptions'` and [`:h fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo-table) shows that we can't achieve what you want to do with built-in options.

Now you have two choices: either find an external program which will format your code as you want or write a function used by `formatexpr`.

About `formatexpr` the help ([`:h 'formatexpr'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatexpr%27)) doesn't tell us a lot about how to write the function. You can have a look at [this Vim dev](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-write-formatexpr-script-td1197037.html) mailing list post and [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2848/1841) to get some very basic examples. I think writing such a function might be a lot of trouble since you would need to re-implement the current behavior of `gq` *and* add the quotes formatting.

So I would say that your best bet is to find an external tool to do the formatting and set your `formatprg` properly. (Remember to set it in an ftplugin so that it only affects javascript code.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @statox, I had a go at writing something that can be used with `formatprg`. At the time of writing it's still a big rough but it will do what you need.

To use it, you need to install my vim script:

1. clone the repo, it has a helper vim script and the NodeJS script that does the formatting

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/tomsaleeba/js-string-literal-breaker.git /tmp/jsslb
   # note, we're cloning to /tmp for this demo but if you like the script, clone
   # somewhere more permanent
   ```
2. start vim with your test case in a buffer

   ```
   cat <<EOF | vim
   console.log(
      "This is a really long line that I want to format, and it is inside of a quote"
   )
   EOF
   ```
3. source my vim script

   ```
   :source /tmp/jsslb/script.vim
   ```
4. enable the formatter

   ```
   <leader>j
   ```
5. move the cursor to line 2
6. run the formatter `gqq`
7. the buffer should now look like

   ```
   console.log(
      "This is a really long line that I want to format, and it is inside of a " +
      "quote"
   )
   ```