# What exactly does \%(...\) and \z(...\) do?

Tags: regular-expression

I know `\(...\)` is Vim's way to create a capturing group. It was listed under the *atom* entry in Vim's doc. There are two other forms of atom, `\%(...\)` and `\z(...\)`. The document is not very clear on what exactly does they do. Could anyone help to explain it please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`/\%(`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%25%28) permits to define a group as with [`/\(`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%28), but we cannot refer to text matched by this group with [`/\1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c1) or with [`submatch()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#submatch%28%29) from commands like `:substitute` or functions like `matchlist()`.

Having a group permits to apply counting and other things to the group ([`/star`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fstar), [`/\+`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%2b), [`/\?`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2f%5c%3f)...)

While `/\%(` *hides*, [`/\z(`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%2f%5cz%28) seems to do the *opposite*, it exports a group found outside the context where it has been found. It seems to apply only to syntax highlighting. I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So `\%(` is kind of like non-capturing group to me.

Comment: This is exactly a non capturing group.

Comment: Yes, `/\z(` is only valid for syntax highlighting definitions, because you need to define `start` and `end` patterns and you might want to make sure, that the part matched in a start pattern is also in an end pattern available

Answer (score 2):

you can also use it like this

```
  :%s/file\zsName/Path/ge
```

which would substitute `fileName` with `filePath` without you having to retype `file` or any other more bothersome to type word just used to identify the search term

use `:help /\zs` for more info.
just learned about it here:
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/project-wide-find-and-replace/

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This is useful information, but I'm not sure it applies directly to the question (`\z` vs. `\zs`).

Comment: Afaik it's the same, but instead of creating a group with (...) you use it as an argument for the substitution expression (the s in \zs)

Comment: Not quite. `\zs` (and cousin ze) make the whole match pretend to start (end) in different places. They have more in common with positive lookbehinds (aheads).

Comment: Ah, I understand. You may delete this then.

Comment: On the other hand it was the first thing I found when searching for \zs so maybe keep it up for other lost people

Comment: Maybe best to have a new question for `\zs` (and `\ze`) and post this answer there? That should hopefully go to the top of search results.

Comment: @MartinTournoij yeah that seems to be the cleanest approach, I was thinking along this lines as well... What do you figure the initial question could be? Something like this: "How to use \zs to search and replace substrings?" Or is this to convoluted?

Comment: I'd just phrase it as "What exactly does \zs and \ze do?" with a body similar to this: "The help page is not very clear on what exactly does they do. Could anyone help to explain it please?", and then post an answer with a brief general description + some examples on how it's useful (like yours).